# Encrypt and store your pkcs12 keystore using HSM software

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, certificate, pkcs#12

Does anybody know how I can encrypt and store my .p12 file (generated by openSSL).

I already tried & worked with softHSM and its tokens. The problem with Softhsm is that it only imports PKCS8 (.pem) files.
I did some research about other software like SignServer but this was so complicated i couldn't find out if it is possible to store pkcs12 files.

Eventually I want to achieve this: store my pkcs12 file somewhere safe encrypted. But I need to have the possibility to call the .P12 later through a java application.

Comment: [pkcs8(1)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs8.html): The **pkcs8** command processes private keys in PKCS#8 format. It can handle both unencrypted PKCS#8 `PrivateKeyInfo` format and `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` format with a variety of PKCS#5 (v1.5 and v2.0) and PKCS#12 algorithms.

Comment: By storing in a secure module, you mean encrypting with a pass-phrase? Have you tried encrypting the pkcs12 file in openssl? Check this link:https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html